# print to file from c#

Tags: c#, printing, printer-control-language

How can I generate a .pcl file from c# ? Suppose i have a text file, or an xls file and I want to print it, I can check the print to file chekbox and i get a file with extension .pcl. How can I achieve this from code, from c#? Most printer drivers know to generate pcl as I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is much too vague to allow a good answer.  There are many variants and versions of PCL.  Best thing to do is to install the printer driver of a HP device that's similar to the whatever device is going to use the .pcl.  If that's unspecified, pick a HP laser printer that as old as possible.

Generate the file by using the PrintDocument class.  You'll need to set the PrinterSettings.PrintToFile property to True and assign PrinterSettings.PrintFileName.